# How to react to incoming files

Tags: systemd

I need to process to file added to a directory, then remove them.  Files can be large (20KiB to 5 GiB) and arrive slowly (via `scp` or `ftp`).  How can I monitor a path (possibly with a `systemd.path` unit) and only react when the new file has finished writing?  I find that my services always trigger when the first bytes of the file are written, causing failures because the complete file isn't present.

---

#### Attempt 1 (`DirectoryNotEmpty=`)

I use a `*.path` with `DirectoryNotEmpty=`.

Pros:

- Looks like what I want

Cons:

- Triggers too early.  Files are still transferring when I process them, thus they are incomplete (corrupt).

```
# /etc/systemd/system/incoming.path

[Path]
DirectoryNotEmpty=/var/incoming

# /etc/systemd/system/incoming.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/incoming

# /usr/local/bin/incoming

for i in /var/incoming/*; do
  process $i
  rm $i
done
```

#### Attempt 2 (Poll)

I use a `*.timer` to trigger the script once per minute

Pros:

- Simple

Cons:

- Works about 90% of the time for small files, 0% for large files.
- Adds up to 1 minute of delay to the pipeline
- Journal logs cluttered with starting/stopping the incoming unit

```
# /etc/systemd/system/incoming.timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=minutely

# /etc/systemd/system/incoming.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/incoming

# /usr/local/bin/incoming

for i in /var/incoming/*; do
  process $i
  rm $i
done
```

#### Attempt 3 (Poll plus md5)

I continue to poll, but I also only process small `*md5` files which are only sent by the clients after sending the main thing. These are smaller than 1 MTU, so I hope they can not be interrupted half-way through writing.

Pros:

- Seems to works all of the time (but not sure if garunteed)

Cons:

- Adds up to 1 minute of delay to the pipeline
- Journal logs cluttered with starting/stopping the incoming unit
- More complicated for users.  User scripts need to generate `md5sum` and then send that file *after* sending the main file.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/incoming.timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=minutely

# /etc/systemd/system/incoming.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/incoming

# /usr/local/bin/incoming

for i in /var/incoming/*.md5; do
  file=$(basename $i .md5)
  process $file
  rm $file $file.md5
done
```

Comment: Whatever the method to be used, use atomic changes: transfer a file to a (hidden) directory in the same filesystem, then (from sftp or ftp, probably out of luck with scp) move the file to the target directory: either the file is present and complete, or it's not present.

Comment: As it is, one could imagine the md5 method could work 99.9999% of the time and fail the remaining .0001% because for some unforeseen reason the few bytes to be written in the file were delayed and an empty .md5 file was processed.

Comment: Why not use inotifywatch? (part of the package inotify-tools on my system.)

Comment: @A.B I agree with the atomic changes, but how can I know when it's safe to move the file?

Comment: @JdeHaan I knew about inotify, but not this tool.  It looks useful.  `close_write` looks like a promising event to look for.

Comment: The client moves the file: PUT + RENAME done by the client. Can't use scp for this though: sftp instead.

Comment: `inotifywatch -e close_write /var/incoming` looked promising.  On an SCP write, it only triggers one event, and that's after the write is complete.  But I still need to poll though a SIGINT, then parse its stdout to see of an event happened.  Even then, it tells me the directory had something written, but doesn't tell me what the new file is.  I need to walk the directory to find that, and that gives some possibility of new things entering at that time.

Comment: @Stewart : Why not trigger on the create too and match those against the closes?

Answer (score 1):

Since the only issue with **"Attempt 1"** is the files are still open, you could modify your script to use `lsof` and `sleep` to ensure the file is closed before processing.

Something like this:

```bsh
# /usr/local/bin/incoming

for i in /var/incoming/*; do
  while [ "$(lsof $i)" != "" ]; do
    sleep 1
  done
  process $i
  rm $i
done
```

Thinking about it a bit more, there is the potential for a race condition if `systemd` calls the script again while an already running script is waiting for a file to close.

Something like this is somewhat less prone to errors resulting from race conditions (there's still room for improvement):

```bsh
for i in /var/incoming/*; do
    while [ -e $i ]; do
        if [ "$(lsof $i)" != "" ]
        then
            sleep 1
        else
            process $i
            rm $i
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: While I don't usually like sleep, I really like this solution because it keeps the client-side simple.  No need to generate md5s or `PUT, then RENAME`.  All heavy-work is done on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to do this -- in a mailserver, for example -- is to have the writing process write to an incoming directory and move the file to the processing directory when it's complete.  The processing service can then act on new files arriving without needing to worry that the incoming file is still being written.

This does rely on being able to rename into place as part of the uploading process, but lets you then use the `DirectoryNotEmpty` functionality you had been trying to use.